# Different Controllers in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two controller Class in spring mvc 4..
    /admin/brand   it's work , but  /admin  not working..
   How to map request /admin  ??  I now , I can map all methods in one Controller, but I want it different controllers.
Sorry for bad english...

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/brand")
    public class AdminController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String admin() {
            return "adminbrand";
        }
    }

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminBrandController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String admin() {
        return "adminBrand";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Controller
public class AdminBrandController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/brand", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminBrand() {
        return "adminBrand";
    }
}

@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String admin() {
        return "admin";
    }
}
```